# When filing a new non-provisional that's a CIP of two prior applications, can you use only the latter date in the ADS to extend the patent life?

Tags: continuation-in-part

I am filing a new nonprovisional application that is a CIP that will reference two prior nonprovisional applications - in the ADS if I claim priority the "July 2020" does the *20-year time limit* start "July 2020" or "Feb. 2018"?

The present Application is a Continuation-in-Part of patent application entitled “XXXXXXXXXXXXX,” filed 8 Feb. 2018 and assigned filing Ser. No. 13/000,000, and is related to co-pending patent application entitled “XXXXXXXXXXXXX,” filed 29 Jul. 2020 and assigned filing Ser. No. 14/000,000, both Patent Applications incorporated herein by reference in their entireties.

Thank you in advance for your help.

JB